# Typescript: Constrain function generic type based on the expected return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I look to fix the typing of the `addRandomValue` function, so that the Typescript compiler doesn't allow the below call, because `baz` is not in `FooBar`.

```
type WithRandomNumber<T> = T & { randomValue: number; };

function addRandomValue<T>(inputObj: T): WithRandomNumber<T> {
    return {
        ...inputObj,
        randomValue: Math.random(),
    };
}

interface FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};

const resultObj: WithRandomNumber<FooBar> = addRandomValue({
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: 100,
    baz: true,
});
```

That is, I want to constrain the generic `T` of `addRandomValue` (and hence the type of `inputObj`), so that if the expected return type is `WithRandomNumber<Foobar>` (because that's the variable type that we assign the return value to), then `T` has to equal `FooBar`.

Comment: Looks like it works fine if you [actually pass the generic argument?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgJQIYDsAmB7AtgOQFdcAjCAJwB4AVAPigF4pqoAyKAbynIx1wDVUAG0IQAXFHTEy5ANxQAvrICwAKDUAzQugDGwONnRRUmTGix5BIiDVoAKOOjCFgAeRIArCdQCUE+EjmfESkFLacalBR3BDAhORGHJHRKQB06Y7Obp4ANMkpUTwWAsKiEgCyqEipRXx2PnmqKUpqCmpqjsAUGqg60ABi2NgAQqjkEU3RGkMSAM7A5I4A5iqTUSRjElKhcq2rajqG8zGzhELZHozGpkGWpTaDI2P2SWtQ09gSAOSIEEJC2C+jRSG3IEgAjAAGSHA6IbABeEgWokaCh8qyAA)

Comment: It does, but I wonder if the compiler could be smart enough to infer it, if we tell it the type we want returned (by assigning it to a variable of that type). This is the reason I phrased my question as "fix the typing of the function", not the way we call the function. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The problem isn't that the compiler isn't smart enough, it has to do with how Javascript is evaluated per the spec. Since you don't pass the generic argument at the call site it infers type `{foo... bar... baz...}` and evaluates the RH expression *then* assigns the result to the LH var with the type you've declared,. Because TS is structural typed that is indeed a valid assignment since it has all of the properties required by FooBar.

Comment: "Because TS is structural typed that is indeed a valid assignment since it has all of the properties required by FooBar." Based on this logic, shouldn't `const fooBar: FooBar = { foo: 'hello', bar: 100, baz: true };` also be a valid assignment? It has all of the properties required by FooBar, but the compiler does complain in this case.

Comment: Only for object literals. See the answer I just posted, specifically the last bit. The thing is that object literals are statically verifiable (unlike references which aren't resolvable until runtime) the compiler can be stricter about them.

Comment: Interesting. By the compiler "being smart", I meant it being able to statically verify T based on the following logic: 
1. "`WithRandomNumber<T>` has to equal `WithRandomNumber<FooBar>`" --> 
2. "`T` has to equal `FooBar`"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229115/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-bzyr).

Comment: Can you use -> `const resultObj  = addRandomValue<WithRandomNumber<FooBar>>({`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force the compiler to balk at the assignment based on the LH type declaration, you instead must pass the generic argument when you call the function:

```typescript
type WithRandomNumber<T> = T & { randomValue: number; };

function addRandomValue<T>(inputObj: T): WithRandomNumber<T> {
    return {
        ...inputObj,
        randomValue: Math.random(),
    };
}

interface FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};

const resultObj = addRandomValue<FooBar>({
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: 100,
    baz: true,
});
```

The problem isn't that the compiler isn't smart enough, it has to do with how Javascript is evaluated per the spec. Since you don't pass the generic argument at the call site it infers type `{foo: string bar: number, baz: boolean }` and evaluates the RH expression *then* it assigns the result to the LH var with the type you've declared. Because TS is structurally-typed that is indeed a valid assignment since it has all of the properties required by FooBar:

```
const foo = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: 100,
    baz: true,
};

const bar: FooBar = foo;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgJQIYDsAmB7AtgOQFdcAjCAJwB4AVAPigF4pqoAyKAbynIx1wDVUAG0IQAXFHTEy5ANxQAvrICwAKDUAzQugDGwONnRRUmTGix5BIiDVoAKOOjCFgAeRIArCdQCUE+EjmfESkFLacalBR3BDAhORGHJHRKQB06Y7Obp4ANMkpUTwWAsKiEgCyqEipRXx2PnmqKUpqCmpqjsAUGqg60ABi2NgAQqjkEU3RGkMSAM7A5I4A5iqTUSRjElKhcq2rajqG8zGzhELZHozGpkGWpTaDI2P2SWtQ09gSAOSIEEJC2C+jRSG3IEgAjAAGSHA6IbABeEgWokaCh8+1Uh3Qxw+V1eKQ+31+-0BsPWmygUJh+SgCKR5BRe3amKOwFpFMeo3GTA+8gA9HyoHBZu9HBADqz2YioJyxniaYSoD8-gCgTTQRDoWSpfSUVABZJsGzpuMhAgKMIRUhsIQlogmaogA)